# Crud app API POST error, not able to find the issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, crud

Making a crud app with Node and Mongo.

While updating a user the API is not able to POST the data and returning an error in the browser `Cannot POST /update-user`

I am able to add a user, but while updating the user it is returning an error.

This is my Add user page:

```
<!-- include header -->
<%- include('include/_header') %>
<!-- /include header -->

<!--Main site-->
<main id="site-main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box-nav d-flex justify-between">
            <div class="filter">
                <a href="/"><i class='fas fa-angle-double-left'></i>All Users</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-title text-center">
            <h2 class='text-dark'>New User</h2>
            <span class='text-light'>Use the form below to create a new account</span>
        </div>
        <!-- add user form -->
        <%- include('include/_form') %>
    </div>
</main>
<!--Main site-->

<!-- include footer -->
<%- include('include/_footer') %>
<!-- /include footer -->
```

This is the footer:

```
    <script src="<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/index.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>

This is the Index.js connected to the footerL:

   
$("#add_user").submit(function(event){
    alert("Data inserted successfully");
})

$("#update_user").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var unindexed_array = $(this).serializeArray();
    var data = {}

    $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
        data[n['name']] = n['value']
    })

    
})
```

This is the index.js connected to the footer:

```
$("#add_user").submit(function(event){
    alert("Data inserted successfully");
})

$("#update_user").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var unindexed_array = $(this).serializeArray();
    var data = {}

    $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
        data[n['name']] = n['value']
    })

    
})
```

This is the Update user form:

```
<!-- include header -->
<%- include('include/_header') %>
<!-- /include header -->

  <!-- Main Site -->
  <main id="site-main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box-nav d-flex justify-between">
           <div class="filter">
               <a href="/"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> All Users</a>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-title text-center">
            <h2 class="text-dark">Update User</h2>
            <span class="text-light">Use the below form to Update an account</span>
        </div>

        <!-- add user form -->
         <!-- form handling -->
 <form method="POST" id="update_user">
    <div class="new_user">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="text-light">Name</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= user._id %>">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<%= user.name %>" placeholder="Mark Stoenis">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="text-light">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<%= user.email%>" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender" class="text-light">Gender</label>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="gender" value="Male" <%= user.gender == 'Male' ? 'checked' : '' %>>
                <label for="radio-2" class="radio-label">Male</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="gender" value="Female"  <%= user.gender == 'Female' ? 'checked' : '' %> >
                <label for="radio-3" class="radio-label">Female</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender" class="text-light">Status</label>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="status" value="Active" <%= user.status == 'Active' ? 'checked' : '' %> >
                <label for="radio-4" class="radio-label">Active</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="status" value="Inactive" <%= user.status == 'Inactive' ? 'checked' : '' %> >
                <label for="radio-5" class="radio-label">Inactive</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn text-dark update">Save</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
       
    </div>
</main>
<!-- /Main Site -->

<!-- include footer -->
<%- include('include/_footer') %>
<!-- /include footer -->
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I am not able to post, as soon as I use POST to update a user. It's showing "Cannot POST /update-user" on the browser.